# How can I convert a string into an ID?

Tags: java, android

I have to convert a string like "R.drawable.photo" into an integer that contain the same thing. How can I do?

```
<string name="id1">R.drawable.photo</string>
```

I need to get an ID that contain "R.drawable.photo"

Comment: Can you perhaps share a bit more about your use case? It's unclear what IDs you're planning to translate from/to.

Comment: I need to obatian the id "R.drawable.photo" from the string

Comment: I think the bigger question here is _why_ you have to do this? Considering that `R.string.id1` will never change during the lifetime of the app, why would you try to "parse" `R.string.id1` into `R.drawable.photo` instead of just using `R.drawable.photo` directly?

Comment: Because in my application there is an array in a xml file that contain a lot of strings and I need to extract one randomly and use it to set an ImageView

Comment: Why not instead have an array of drawable ids inside your java/kotin code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it with the `getIdentifier()` method:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("photo", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

`getResources()` and `getPackageName()` may need a `Context` if this code is not inside an activity:

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("photo", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

If the string has the `R.drawable.` prefix, then:

```
String str = "R.drawable.photo"
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(str.replace("R.drawable.", ""), "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: I've already tried it but when I try to use the id the debbuger show his value is 0

Comment: Problem solved, I had a problem with the res directory. Thank you

Comment: Fine if  it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("myString", 
        "drawable", getPackageName());
```

replace `myString` above with your value of string, which is "`photo`"